# How do I determine which Internet Explorer version is newer based on the versioning information dialog?

Tags: internet-explorer

I have two machines running Internet Explorer.

I'm having trouble understanding the version information on the about dialog.

I understand that the versioning system has major and minor version and so forth, as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/969393/information-about-internet-explorer-versions).

It would seem that the version 11.2439.14393.0 is newer than 11.0.96600.19356 -- however I'm unable to upgrade the version 11.0.96600.19356 to a newer version.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [this discussion at Thurrott.com](https://www.thurrott.com/forums/microsoft/microsoft/thread/whats-the-current-version-of-ie11), the version is just "11". The rest is linked to your OS build. So your first screenshot, with `9600`, is from Windows 8.1. And the second screenshot, with `14393`, is Windows 10 with the 1607 Anniversary Update.

Also note:

> For some reason, in the IE version number, these minor and major numbers have been put in reverse order.

The "Update Versions" field is what will tell you which is "newer". In your case, your upper screenshot (11.0.125) is newer than the lower screenshot (11.0.80).

Comment: Additionally, the higher update version also correlates with a higher KB article (4498206 vs 4343205)

Comment: Note also that the year of copyright is two years later; 2013 vs 2015, which is very confusing.

Comment: The Windows 8.1 build number is not reversed.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the "latest" IE version will differ between different Windows OS versions - specifically, it is completely expected that one system has an "older" version, but there is no available update